# npm live-server not reading php files

Tags: git, github, npm-live-server

I'm very new to Git, and I just installed [live server](https://github.com/tapio/live-server) and I run it via terminal. I noticed that it only runs .html files rather than .php files. It basically skips reading them so instead of running index.php, it gives me a directory listing. If I use an html file, it works fine. Is there any work around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no. This server works only with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

If you want PHP you need more powerful server (Apache, nginx, lighttpd, etc.)